# Why tilda take long time to appear on my laptop?

Tags: compiz, software-recommendation

Im using [tilda](http://tilda.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) on 2 computer, a desktop and a notebook, both with ubuntu LL 10.04 and Compiz.

The notebook has 6Gb RAM, 4 Cpu's (Core i3 330M) @ 2,13GHz, and an ATI Radeon HD 5650 (with ati closed drivers).. its a new notebook.
The Desktop has 2 Cpu, 4Gb ram and an Intel graphic card.. its 5 years old.

I dont know why, but when i show/hide tilda (i use it in fullscreen mode with opacity), in the desktop show up instantly, instead in the notebook take 2~3 seconds.

Why the notebook is slower, even if it is more powerfull?

Can be a matter of drivers/graphic card type, or there is some configuration i can check?

On both I did install tilda from ubuntu software sources.

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that it happens when i try to maximize every window (a terminal, google chrome, gedit, etc..), if i press F11 to maximize it: in the notebook it takes few seconds, in the desktop is instantly.

Could it be a compiz setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a driver problem.

I solved installing the latest version of ATI drivers, adding two repositories:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu lucid main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu lucid main
key: http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3B22AB97AF1CDFA9
```

and then `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

I would try re-installing; also maybe checking to see if the key binding you use launches another process in the background that you may be unaware of.

Open `top` and then run tilda, maybe that will help you troubleshoot better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [Guake](http://guake.org/) ;)

Just an idea..

Comment: It wasnt a tilda problem, but it happens rmaximizings all the windows, so i thought was a driver related problem